# octomap using pointcloud data without odomoetry

Tags: ros, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to generate a 3D map of the environment using octomap. I have 3D scan dataset but I do not have tf.
According to http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server ,

> sensor data frame → /map (static world
> frame, changeable with parameter
> frame_id)

> Required transform of sensor
> data into the global map frame if you
> do scan integration. This information
> needs to be available from an external
> SLAM or localization node.

I do not have access to this transform. I am rather trying to achive localization by using the continuous scans.
Can someone suggest what can be done?
Is there a good tutorial to use octomap on a precaptured dataset?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191337/octomap-using-pointcloud-data-without-odomoetry/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I guess the only problem for you is not to think of 3D mapping but to establish the tf for your platform in the first place. If you have a single RGB-D sensor mounted on a tripod like in my case, I would write a launch file establishing all related tf frames and also using  map_server  to load in a blank map or using gmapping package to render a map to complete the tf tree as well as the necessary topic for octomap.

So, at this point, your tf tree should look like: "map --> odom --> base_footprint --> camera_link".

Then call in octomap_server in your launch file, make sure to remap the "cloud_in" with your 3D camera's depth topic. Also, set the parameter "latch" to false if you don't have any map to load in. Don't forget to set the parameter "frame_id" to /map,
If you succeeded in doing all these procedures, then you can render octomap with Marker Arrays on Rviz.

This is just my case, if your are using other sensors, modify corresponding topics according to your needs. Good luck !

---

Originally posted by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) with karma: 106 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0